# full page table within paragraph

Tags: tables, floats

I have several large tables in my thesis. Some of them are about 2/3 of a page, and placing them at the top of a page works fine, even when a paragraph has to be broken to allow for the space.

My problem is that a few of my tables are full page tables, and LaTeX *always* puts them in between paragraphs (leaving lots of white spaces before the table). What I want is for the text to be typeset as if the page with the table weren't there, and then just insert the page with the table in between. Is that possible?

Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{report}
\textheight 9.5in\topmargin -.5in\textwidth 6in\hoffset 0.2cm
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}



\begin{document}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother\clearpage{\pagestyle{plain}\cleardoublepage}
%
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0.02in}
\lineskip=.5ex \baselineskip 5ex 
%
% Define pagestyle
%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}


\chapter{Introduction}
This is randomly generated text. \blindtext
\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\caption{Long table caption\newline
\footnotesize{\blindtext }
 }\label{tab:firsttable}
 {\footnotesize
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
 \begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lccccc}\toprule
dep. var.:  $\sigma^M_{\tau+15\text{min}}$ & \textbf{I} & \textbf{II} &      \textbf{III} & \textbf{IV} & \textbf{V} \\ 
\midrule
$\overline{\text{GD}}^{\text{buy}}_\tau(\widehat{\lambda})$ &   & -0.034 &   -0.030 & -0.030 & -0.028 \\ 
 &  & (-6.82) & (-6.83) & (-5.44) & (-5.23) \\ 
$\overline{\text{GD}}^{\text{sell}}_\tau(\widehat{\lambda})$ &   & -0.021 &  -0.017 & -0.011 & -0.011 \\ 
 &  & (-3.51) & (-3.14) & (-1.50) & (-1.56) \\ 
$\overline{\text{SLOPE}}_\tau$ &  &  & 0.013 & 0.017 & 0.015 \\ 
&  &  & (1.87) & (2.79) & (2.26) \\ 
$\overline{\text{relSPR}}_\tau$ &  &  & 0.028 & 0.022 & 0.021 \\ 
 &  &  & (5.41) & (2.28) & (2.12) \\ 
$\overline{\text{NT}}_\tau$ &  &  & 0.008 &  & 0.008 \\ 
 &  &  & (1.34) &  & (1.24) \\ 
$\overline{\text{AQ}}_\tau$ &  &  & -1.17 &  & 0.001 \\ 
 &  &  & (-0.02) &  & (0.28) \\ 
$\overline{\text{AMR}}_\tau$ &  &  &  & 0.002 & 0.002 \\ 
 &  &  &  & (0.47) & (0.58) \\ 
$\overline{\text{logQS}}_\tau$ &  &  &  & 0.014 & 0.014 \\ 
 &  &  &  & (0.94) & (0.96) \\ 
$\overline{\text{DHW}}_\tau$ &  &  &  & 0.003 & 0.003 \\ 
 &  &  &  & (0.62) & (0.60) \\ 
$\sigma^M_\tau$ & 0.038 & 0.023 & 0.013 & 0.015 & 0.011 \\ 
 & (6.82) & (4.96) & (2.51) & (3.30) & (2.19) \\ 
constant & 0.179 & 0.749 & -0.796 & -0.947 & -0.889 \\ 
 & (7.94) & (8.07) & (-2.54) & (-3.14) & (-2.87) \\ 
 &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
adj. $R^2 (\%)$ & 16.94 & 24.62 & 28.81 & 28.88 & 28.95 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*} 
}
\end{table}
\Blindtext
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[p]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
 \caption{Another long caption\newline
  \footnotesize{\blindtext}}\label{tab:secondtable}
 {\footnotesize
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
   \begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth} {@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lccccccccccc}\toprule
 & \textbf{IC$_t$} & \textbf{RC$_t$} & \textbf{VRP$_t$} &      \textbf{$\overline{\text{VRPi}}$} & \textbf{log(P$_t$$/$D$_t$)} &  \textbf{log(P$_t$$/$E$_t$)} & \textbf{CAY$_t$} & \textbf{DS$_t$} & \textbf{TS$_t$} & \textbf{RREL$_t$} & \textbf{$\textbf{R}_{\textbf{m}t}-\textbf{R}_{\textbf{f}t}$} \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{ 12}{l}{\textbf{Panel A: Summary Statistics}} \\ 
mean & 0.50 & 0.33 & 2.39 & -25.69 & 3.99 & 3.24 & -0.59 & 1.01 & 1.68 & -1.63 & 0.33 \\ 
 min & 0.19 & 0.05 & -325.93  & -603.13 & 3.16 & 2.71 & -3.73 & 0.55 & -0.53 & -23.17 & -20.49 \\ 
 max & 0.81 & 0.78 & 48.62& 37.44 & 4.41 & 4.83 & 3.14 & 3.38 & 3.70 & 12.83 & 10.37 \\ 
 st. dev. & 0.14 & 0.14 & 33.82 & 66.14 & 0.24 & 0.42 & 2.00 & 0.49 & 1.21 & 7.24 & 4.99 \\ 
 AC(1) & 0.81 & 0.61 & 0.51 & 0.46 & 0.97 & 0.93 & 0.98 & 0.96 & 0.98 & 0.85 & 0.15 \\ 
 AC(2) & 0.73 & 0.46 & 0.26 & 0.30 & 0.94 & 0.86 & 0.95 & 0.89 & 0.94 & 0.82 & -0.05 \\ 
 \midrule
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
 \multicolumn{ 12}{l}{\textbf{Panel B: Unconditional Correlation Matrix}}  \\ 
 IC$_t$ & 1.00 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
 RC$_t$ & 0.57 & 1.00 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
 VRP$_t$ & -0.01 & -0.39 & 1.00 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
 $\overline{\text{VRPi}}$ & -0.05 & -0.24 & 0.90 & 1.00 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
 log(P$_t$$/$D$_t$) & -0.49 & -0.53 & 0.23 & 0.13 & 1.00 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
 log(P$_t$$/$E$_t$) & 0.16 & 0.04 & 0.04 & -0.12 & -0.13 & 1.00 &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
 CAY$_t$ & 0.18 & -0.25 & 0.04 & -0.14 & 0.19 & 0.12 & 1.00 &  &  &  &  \\ 
 DS$_t$ & 0.26 & 0.54 & -0.51 & -0.51 & -0.65 & 0.41 & -0.20 & 1.00 &  &  &  \\ 
 TS$_t$ & 0.47 & 0.39 & -0.06 & -0.02 & -0.40 & 0.39 & -0.08 & 0.42 & 1.00 &  &  \\  
 RREL$_t$ & -0.31 & -0.27 & 0.08 & 0.14 & 0.22 & -0.39 & -0.21 & -0.45 & -0.47 & 1.00 &  \\ 
 $\text{R}_{\text{m}t}-\text{R}_{\text{f}t}$ & -0.02 & -0.29 & 0.32 & 0.28 & 0.10 & 0.12 & 0.00 & -0.23 & 0.01 & 0.13 & 1.00 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

When you compile this you will get 6 pages of random text. Table 1.2 is inserted (as I expected it to be) at the top of page 2, within a paragraph that starts on page 1 and continues after the table on page 2. 
Table 1.2, which takes a full page, starts after a paragraph leaving a white space at the end of page 3. I would like the new paragraph (which now starts at the top of page 5) to start on page 3 and to continue at page 5, inserting table 1.2 on page 4 (which would be the same behaviour as table 1.2).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Have you tried using `\begin{table}[p]` ?

Comment: yes, that's what I am using now. The problem is that it will put the page with the table between two paragraphs, leaving lots of white space before the page with the table. I'd like to insert the page with the table without breaking the paragraphs.

Comment: If you use `[p]` you are forbidding latex using top or bottom of a text page,  so the effect you describe is forced. Just use no option at all (which is same as `[tbp]` )

Comment: If you're still having problems with this, you could post the contents of a small compilable `.tex` file that illustrates this behaviour. That would make it easier for us to diagnose your problem.

Comment: @JohnWickerson thanks! I have added a minimum example to illustrate my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using environment `landscape` for the second table. This environment is not a floating object. In contrary, it causes a page break (via `\clearpage`) to get a new page, where it can change the page layout.

A trick is using package `afterpage`. Put the whole `\begin{landscape}...\end{landscape}` inside `\afterpage`. Then page three is filled and at the next page break, the stuff in `\afterpage` is executed:

```
...
\usepackage{afterpage}
...

\begin{document}
  ...
  \Blindtext
  \afterpage{%
    \begin{landscape}
    ...
    \end{landscape}%
  }
  \Blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Works like charm, thank you very much!